# Nonlocality of gauge-charged particle?

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory

On pp.24 left-hand side of [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.3.011016) there is a statement saying:

*the vortex insertion operator is of course a nonlocal object, which reflects the fact that one cannot insert a gauge-charged particle in the bulk without changing the gauge fields everywhere*

I wonder whether this fact of gauge-charged particle insertion is a general theorem about gauge field theory or just another way of stating the nonlocality of vortex?